# How to Get File using Console application in C#?

Tags: c#

I am building an C# Console Application for GET file which will automatically download the file when I run the console application.

These are my codes:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPIConsoleNEW
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            string bookPath_Pdf = @"D:\VisualStudio\randomfile.pdf";
            string bookPath_xls = @"D:\VisualStudio\randomfile.xls";
            string bookPath_doc = @"D:\VisualStudio\randomfile.docx";
            string bookPath_zip = @"D:\VisualStudio\randomfile.zip";

            string format = "pdf";
            string reqBook = format.ToLower() == "pdf" ? bookPath_Pdf : (format.ToLower() == "xls" ? bookPath_xls : (format.ToLower() == "doc" ? bookPath_doc : bookPath_zip));
            string fileName = "sample." + format.ToLower();

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49209/");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("applicaiton/json"));

                    Console.WriteLine("GET");

                    //converting Pdf file into bytes array
                    var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(reqBook);

                    //adding bytes to memory stream
                    var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

                    //send request asynchronously
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/person");
                    response.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                    //Check that response was successful or throw exception
                    //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    //Read response asynchronously and save asynchronously to file
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:49209/api"))
                        {
                            using (
                            Stream contentStream = await (await client.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
                                fileStream = new FileStream("D:\\VisualStudio\\randomfile.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                        {
                                //copy the content from response to filestream
                                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                                //Console.WriteLine();
                            }   

                        }
                    }

            }
            catch (HttpRequestException rex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rex.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run another ASP.NET application which is my localhost, it only return the default which is value1 and value2 in the Controller. However, I do not have Controller in C# Console Application. I think I just one step away, I had successfully obtain the file and CopyToAsync the file I wanted to download.

Conclusion:
I want when user runs the application it would straight download the file in a place (or can I use SaveFileDialog to let user decide where to save the file).
Please help thanks

**Update:**

At first, I created a ASP.NET Web Application and Create a PersonController and I run the Project. After that I created a console C# Application and then I want to achieve the result of when user runs the console C# Application it would straight download the file to a specific place.

In the first get I uses api/person, and I convert the file int o bytes array and add the bytes array to memory stream. After that, I don't really know what I'm doing is right or wrong. I saw something like CopyToAsync is working then I tried it and implement it but it won't works. My goal is simple I just want to acheive once I run the C# Console application it would straight download the file from a specific localhost address

Comment: I don't think the code makes sense. You make a GET request for api/person, then modify the response by adding some file into the response, why? And what exactly is wrong with the second GET that copies the file? What controller? What value1 and value2? Could you edit the question and explain more clearly what exactly happens and what should happen instead?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I added some file to the response because I want to when I run the console C# application it would straight download the file, sorry I still in learning process

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your problem is that you are sending two GET requests, in case you just want to call `api/student` then save the response into a file then no need for the second request

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:49209/api")//no need for it
```

So your code should be like this:

```
static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        string bookPath_Pdf = @"D:\VisualStudio\randomfile.pdf";
        string bookPath_xls = @"D:\VisualStudio\randomfile.xls";
        string bookPath_doc = @"D:\VisualStudio\randomfile.docx";
        string bookPath_zip = @"D:\VisualStudio\randomfile.zip";

        string format = "pdf";
        string reqBook = format.ToLower() == "pdf" ? bookPath_Pdf : (format.ToLower() == "xls" ? bookPath_xls : (format.ToLower() == "doc" ? bookPath_doc : bookPath_zip));
        string fileName = "sample." + format.ToLower();

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49209/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("applicaiton/json"));

                Console.WriteLine("GET");

                //converting Pdf file into bytes array
                var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(reqBook);

                //adding bytes to memory stream
                var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

                //send request asynchronously
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/person");
                response.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                //Check that response was successful or throw exception
                //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                //Read response asynchronously and save asynchronously to file
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                    {
                        using (fileStream = new FileStream("D:\\VisualStudio\\randomfile.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                        {
                            //copy the content from response to filestream
                            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                            //Console.WriteLine();
                        }   
                    }
                }
           }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException rex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Also it would be good to print a message for the user telling him that logging data from server into file(File path) is in progress:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Logging data from server into file (D:\\VisualStudio\\randomfile.pdf");
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run this console application users still can't download the file(sample.pdf)? How can I make it possible?

Comment: So you want two things save response from `api/person` into file, and also downloading sample.pdf file ? @Cheeseburger

Comment: I just need one thing which is when I run this console application it would the sample.pdf file on PC.

Comment: Ok good, now this sample.pdf are you filling it from http call `api/person` , or it is just a file on the server and you need to download it?